# Oracle Data Modeller: Recursive One to many relationship

Tags: oracle, data-modeling, erd, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I am having trouble understanding how to create recursive one to many relationships in a logical model built by Oracle data modeller.

The relational relationship should be similar to this i.e Manager ID is a FK for the same table 
[image]

I have my logical model set up as so:

[image]

However, when I engineer to relational this is my result.

[image]

This behaves fine if I am creating a relationship for two different tables, Manager and Employee. PK on source table appears as FK target table.

[image]

How can I set up my logical model to create one FK called managerID with a one-to-many relationship on the same table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i faced it initially.I think you have done the steps correctly, its just the notation is not showing the linkage as i see the linkage in the diagram but the attribute is not visible in the diagram.Try switching from Barker notation.

go to View>>Logical Diagram Notation >>Information Engineering Notation

let me know if this resolved your mystery :)